# Can't get a react component to render using routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I am new to react and I'm trying to render a component called `{Chat}` in a container using routing, but it doesn't give any output (or errors). Here's my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios, { baseURL } from "../../services/config";
import "./Join.css";
import convIcon from "../../assets/selectIcon.png";
import Chat from "../Chat/Chat";

render() {
const { name, room, groups } = this.state;
const { match } = this.props;
const groupsList =
  groups.length > 0 &&
  groups.map(group => {
    return (
      <Link className="chatLink" to={`${match.url}/joinChat/chat`}>
        <div className="chatList">
          <img src={convIcon} title="logo" className="chatIcon" alt="" />
          <h2 className="groupName">
            {group.name}
            <span className="timestamp">2:30 PM</span>
          </h2>
          <span className="lastMsg">Last message text</span>
        </div>
      </Link>
    );
  });
  return (
   <div className="joinOuterContainer">
    <div className="joinInnerContainer">
     <h1 className="heading">Conversations</h1>
     <div className="chatListContainer">{groupsList}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <Route path={`${match.url}/joinChat/Chat`} component={Chat}/>
   </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: Where is Router?

Comment: Most probably the issue is coming from how you pass the `path` to `<Route />`. I guess it should be without the `match.url`.

Comment: maybe it's because you have capital c `Chat` in your Route but `chat` lowercase in your Link